# How to use ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(int,int) in Java to find a specific number that matches a specific expression?

Tags: java, algorithm, java-stream

I want to generate a ifinite IntStream using ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(int,int), for example:

`ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 20)`

As I understand, this code will generate an IntStream for example
`{2, 7, 4, 0, 5, 9, 3...}`

Then I wanted to have the first number that matches a specific expression, for example

*the number should be dividable by 3*

In this case, the number should be 9. So the question is, how can I get this number using stream operation?

Comment: Tell us what have you done so far, what have you read, what have you tried.

Comment: `In this case, the number should be 9` - why `9`  and not `0` ? `0` precedes `9`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`ThreadLocalRandom#ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#ints(int,int)) returns an infinite [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), you'll need to use [`IntStream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter(java.util.function.IntPredicate)) and [`IntStream#findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#findFirst()) to short-circuit it:

```
OptionalInt divisibleByThree = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
    .ints(0, 20)
    .filter(i -> i % 3 == 0)
    .findFirst();
```

Printing this may return the following:

```
OptionalInt[12]
```

Comment: `Then I wanted to have the first number that matches a specific expression` - I guess you should use `findFirst()` and not `findAny()` since the order is crucial.